# Nifi: code in executeScript processor doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, apache-nifi

in this  code  i 
 wan to save  lastDate  in array and use  it to  increment  startDate and endDate  atribute  value automatically.but it  doesn't  generate  flowfile. 
**I try to  Fix  it  but it  can't create  flofwile   what  should  i change?**

```
 var OutputStreamCallback = Java.type("org.apache.nifi.processor.io.OutputStreamCallback");
var StandardCharsets = Java.type("java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets");

Date.prototype.isValid = function () {
    return (Object.prototype.toString.call(this) === "[object Date]")
        && !isNaN(this.getTime());
};

var toDate = endDate.getValue(),
    parameter1=parameter.getValue(),
    count1=count.getValue();

function addDays(date, days) {
    var result =new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);

    return formatDate(result);
}
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

var flowFile = session.create();
if(flowFile==null) {
    var param = 8;
    //count = Number(count1);
   //var item = item + count1;
    var endDate1 = addDays(toDate, param);
    var startDate = toDate;
    var arr = [];
    arr.push(endDate1);

}
    if(arr.length>1){
        startDate1=arr.pop();
        var endDate1 = addDays(startDate1, param);
        var startDate = startDate1;
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'startDate', startDate1);
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'endDate', endDate1);
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'parameter', parameter);
    }
    else {
        var param = 8;
        var endDate1 = addDays(toDate, param);
        var startDate = toDate;
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'count', 1);
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'startDate', startDate);
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'endDate', endDate1);
        flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, 'parameter', parameter1);
    }

    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);
```

**it  doesn't  trow  exceptions  but  not  make  flowfile  too

1. ** should  i  add (flowfile==null)  to make  newly creted flowfile  intialized?
2. Do  you reccomend  me  something  to make my code more persistent and  fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are creating a new flowfile, which is guaranteed not to be `null`. You then evaluate `if (flowFile == null)`, which will always return `false`. You only initialize your variables `param`, `endDate1`, `startDate`, and `arr` inside that control block. The remaining code won't execute as you expect, and you reference variables that have not been defined (`parameter1` or `var toDate = endDate.getValue()` for example). `flowFile` won't have any of the attributes you expect when it is transferred.

You do not need an `ExecuteScript` processor to do any of this. Use `UpdateAttribute` with the Apache NiFi Expression Language to perform simple date math.

If this starts a flow, use a `GenerateFlowFile` processor to initially create the flowfile and send it to `UpdateAttribute`. If you are receiving a flowfile from elsewhere, you only need `UpdateAttribute` (but you need two; one to create the *number of days to add* variable and one to perform the math -- or if that delta is constant, just one and change the variable reference to be a literal number).

Processors with dynamic properties defined ([template as GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/5d52e434d5fdfa00d572877d6deb5640)):

```
GenerateFlowFile:
startDate: ${now():toNumber()} <- puts the start date in "number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970 00:00:00.000 GMT" format
numberOfDaysToAdd: 8 <- or whatever static or dynamic value you want here
startDateFormatted: ${now():format("YYYY-MM-dd")} <- (optional) startDate in readable format if you need it

UpdateAttribute:
endDate: ${startDate:plus(${numberOfDaysToAdd:multiply(86400000)}):format("YYYY-MM-dd")} <- adds the number of milliseconds in a day * the number of days to the start date and formats it the way you want
```

Your resulting flowfile will look like this:

```
o.a.n.processors.standard.LogAttribute LogAttribute[id=d06d3a2d-015e-1000-0820-087660238327] logging for flow file StandardFlowFileRecord[uuid=6d26df1a-fd52-407e-b549-0599d6ab3a21,claim=,offset=0,name=1636687405556264,size=0]
--------------------------------------------------
Standard FlowFile Attributes
Key: 'entryDate'
    Value: 'Fri Sep 29 18:40:06 PDT 2017'
Key: 'lineageStartDate'
    Value: 'Fri Sep 29 18:40:06 PDT 2017'
Key: 'fileSize'
    Value: '0'
FlowFile Attribute Map Content
Key: 'endDate'
    Value: '2017-10-07'
Key: 'filename'
    Value: '1636687405556264'
Key: 'numberOfDaysToAdd'
    Value: '8'
Key: 'path'
    Value: './'
Key: 'startDate'
    Value: '1506735606982'
Key: 'startDateFormatted'
    Value: '2017-09-29'
Key: 'uuid'
    Value: '6d26df1a-fd52-407e-b549-0599d6ab3a21'
--------------------------------------------------
```

This will be far more performant and stable than using `ExecuteScript`.